# valid word counter out of bounds error

Tags: java

```
{
    public static int WordCount (String cString)
    {       
        String currentWord;
        int index;
        int spacePos;
        int validWordCount=0;
        boolean validWord;
        char upClowC;

        cString=cString.trim()+" ";

        spacePos=cString.indexOf(" ");

        validWord=true;

        for(index=0;index<cString.length();index++)
        {
            currentWord=cString.substring(0,spacePos);
            upClowC=Character.toUpperCase(currentWord.charAt(index));
            if(upClowC<'A'||upClowC>'Z')
            {
                validWord=false;
            }   
        }

        if(validWord==true)
        {
            validWordCount++;
        }

        return validWordCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sentence;

        System.out.println("enter a sentence:");
        sentence=EasyIn.getString();

    WordCount(sentence);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a method which takes a sentence and picks out the valid words (i.e. no numbers or symbols), but I keep getting an out of bounds error.

I can't use an array.

Comment: Please show us the exception you get

Comment: More than the error, there is the fact that this code does not do what the OP expects

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
currentWord = cString.substring(0, spacePos);
upClowC = Character.toUpperCase(currentWord.charAt(index));
```

`currentWord` gets shorter, but `index` is still running from 0 to the length of the string.

General notes:

- Follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and change the name of your method to begin with small letter
- `if(validWord)` is enough when you want to compare something to `true`, otherwise it's like asking "*is it true that the value is true*" instead of simply "*is the value true*"
- Next time post your stack trace to get better and sooner help

Comment: I'd suggest taking that first line out of the `for` loop, that should actually fix the problem. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are doing

```
spacePos = cString.indexOf(" ");
```

And then inside the loop:

```
currentWord = cString.substring(0,spacePos);
upClowC = Character.toUpperCase(currentWord.charAt(index));
```

Now, because of the loop, the index will take values from 0 to your string length minus 1. If your substring (`currentWord`) is smaller than your string - which probably is -, then `currentWord.charAt(index)` will try to index out of the bounds of the substring, which is why you get the error.